# Encoding issue in files names and plots labels axis while using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, encoding

Hi everyone,

I'm using a for loop in a function to plot  biological indicators. My ggsave command is in the function;

My issue is pretty simple : 
when I'm using my loop my plot names (.png) and the axis labels are not written with the good encoding .

```
  fun_dens_spe_pm<-function (donnees_dens_sp_1,pm_peche){

dens_sp<-subset(donnees_dens_sp_1, donnees_dens_sp_1$CodeOnema == pm_peche)
dens_sp$Espece<-as.character(dens_sp$nom_sp)

list_sp_pm<-as.list(unique(dens_sp$nom_sp))  

# # Test
# Esp<-list_sp_pm[[1]]

dens_par_sp<-function (dens_sp, Esp){

  # Selection de l'espèce i présente sur la station 
  dens_sp_i<-subset(dens_sp,dens_sp$nom_sp == Esp)

  # Selection des champs pour création des graphiques

  dens_sp_i<- dens_sp_i[,c("CodeOnema","Date","densite_sp")]
  dens_sp_i$Date<-as.numeric(dens_sp_i$Date)


  # Test du nombre d'années ou l'espèce i est présente sur la chronique
  ifelse(

    # Condition : présence de l'espèce inférieure ou égale à 2 années
    nrow(dens_sp_i) <= 2, 

  # Si oui : Graphique si présence "excetpionnelle" d'une espèce
  p_dens_sp_pm <- ggplot(data = dens_sp_i, aes(x= Date, y = densite_sp)) +
    geom_point(size = 3,col = "firebrick") +
    geom_text(aes(x= Date, y = densite_sp,fill = densite_sp), 
              label=paste0("Présence exceptionnelle de l'espèce en","",Date), color="firebrick") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 6))+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 12))+
    labs(x="Années",y ="Densité spécifique (ind/100 m2)") +
    theme(text = element_text(size=11),plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),legend.position="none")+
    ggtitle(paste0("Evolution de la densité de l'espèce"," ",Esp," ",  "sur la station"," ",pm_peche)),


 # Si non : Graphique  si présence "continue" sur la série temporelle

 p_dens_sp_pm<-ggplot(data = dens_sp_i, aes(x= Date, y = densite_sp,fill = densite_sp)) +
    geom_line(size = 1,col = "dodgerblue2",linejoin = "round")+
    geom_point(size = 3,col = "firebrick") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 6))+
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 12))+
    labs(x="Années",y ="Densité spécifique (ind/100 m2)") +
    theme(text = element_text(size=11),plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),legend.position="none")+
    ggtitle(paste0("Evolution de la densité de l'espèce"," ",Esp," ",  "sur la station"," ",pm_peche)))

  # Visualisation du graphique
  p_dens_sp_pm  

  # Enregistrement du graphe

  nom_graphe <-paste0("Densité_sp","_",Esp,"_",pm_peche,".png")  
  ggsave(plot = p_dens_sp_pm,filename = nom_graphe,device ="png",
         path = paste0("./EEE/graphes/sta_RHP_complete/indicateurs/densite_relative/",pm_peche),
         width = 25, height = 18, units = "cm")
}

# Boucle d'application de la fonction

for (i in seq.int(list_sp_pm)) {

  graphe<-dens_par_sp(dens_sp,list_sp_pm[[i]])
}

}
```

However, when I'm not using the loop everything is okay and I have no encoding issue (See the images in atached files)

[without_loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUP4X.png)
[with_loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eugYW.png)

What do I need to change in my code to solve that?

Thanks

**strong text**

Comment: I finally found the solution by myself :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution :
On windows R's source function does not work with files that includes characters that are not part of the current system encoding. 
To ensure that you are working with the right encoding use :

```
> Sys.setlocale()
```

In my case I got the following :

```
[1]"LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252;LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_France.1252"
```

My system encoding is "WINDOWS-1252" but my functions' scripts seem to be written in an other one (UTF-8).

Go to

Tools > Global Options > Code > Saving

and set the right  default text encoding. When you reopen your scripts, you just need to replace special characters by the desired one's and don't forget to save.